# What adjective or phrase can be used to describe a person who was lucky and escaped deadly situations so many times?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I need a word or a simple phrase to describe a person who was lucky that had faced several deadly situations but ended up surviving. Words like "immortal" did not work since the person can still die but they were just lucky that they could escape death. "Lucky" is also not a word since it is not only exclusively about facing a deadly situation. Is there an English word or phrase for that?

Comment: They *defied all odds.*

Comment: Led a charmed life, until he didn’t.

Comment: Are you looking for something like *bulletproof* in the metaphorical sense, or *lucky* but specifically for avoiding death? Do you want the person to be oblivious to danger, and simply lucky to have survived, or, on the contrary, overconfident because thus far they have survived everything? Does it matter whether they are happy they have survived (Indiana Jones), unaware they have survived (Mr Magoo), or despairing that they always survive (Bruce Banner)?

Comment: Would *having nine lives* do?

Comment: Having used up most of his nine lives.

Comment: To everyone, I think 9 lives worked so probably the correct answer.